# Cassandra: missing ')' at '<missing '

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh, scylla

tried to create the following table:

```
    CREATE TABLE customTableSchema(
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        table_id UUID,
        schema text,
        created_at timestamp,
        last_modified_at timestamp,
    );
```

came up with this error:

```
SyntaxException: line 4:8 missing ')' at '<missing '
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the last comma? "last_modified_at timestamp,"

Comment: yes i did...still same error :(

Comment: the problem is wit the field schema - if you change it to something else and remove the comment on the last field it will work

Comment: it worked when i remove field schema. But why does it cause error? is it cuz conflict with something? @ShlomiLivne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since "schema" is a reserverd keyword, you cannot use your query in current form. If you intend to use it then you can do it as below

```
CREATE TABLE customTableSchema(
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        table_id UUID,
        "schema" text,
        created_at timestamp,
        last_modified_at timestamp,
    );
```

You can refer [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/keywords_r.html) for reserved cql keywords.

Answer (score 7):

The `schema` is reserved keyword in the Cassandra Query Language, so you can't use it (see [this table in the docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/appendices.html#appendix-a)).